# Opencart - Вложенные SEO URL

Tags: url, opencart, seo, чпу

Интересует вот такое: как сделать ЧПУ ссылки такого типа: `https://site.ru/page/content`, то есть чтобы имелась вложенность. Если так и прописать в SEO URL, то выдает страницу с надписью "Страница не найдена", все работает только если не прописывать эту вложенность. SEO URL включен, htaccess имеется. Как провернуть такое?